# Tomcat ignoring post parameters request

Tags: java, tomcat, post, coldfusion

I have an Apache Tomcat server to read request from my webapp.

In my webapp I have a form that is submitted and posts a large number of POST parameters, around 8k~

However when I try to debug the entrypoint, where the HttpServletRequest, I always receive exactly 6841. The inputs from the form are created iterating over a number of elements, meaning that the last ones are exactly the same form as the other that are succeding

I can't show code for NDA reasons.
I discarded the frontend as an issue because with a sniffer I was able to see that the complete post param list is sent.

I believe I'm on the right track, I think Tomcat is dropping the other post params. the post size limit is well beyond the size of the request, and we don't have a post parameter count configured on server.xml (defaults to 10,000 and I don't hit that amount).

All answers I have found are about not sending parameters at all or errors being thrown, in this case they are simply ignored by Tomcat.

Comment: In this case, I suggest you debug tomcat code itself.

Comment: Is it working with less than 6841, let's say 5k POST parameters?

Comment: @AlexBaban yes, 2, 3, 4, 5k, 2k. but drops the others after that odd number of 6841

Comment: I understand. If possible, you could try to combine the data into JSON or even XML and pass it as payload in the body of the request.

Comment: Thanks @AlexBaban, i wasn't trying to be sarcastic, sorry about that. Uhm, maybe the solution is not to solve it but change it, i'll try converting that data into JSON and pass it in the body request. If i recall correctly the standards is to convert the post parameters from a form into a URL encoded separated with ampersands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the number of POST parameters (not size of post) to 20,000 fixed the issue in my case. This was done in the tomcat `server.xml` configuration using [`maxParameterCount`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html):

> The **maxParameterCount** attribute controls the maximum number of
>   parameter and value pairs (GET plus POST) that can be parsed and
>   stored in the request. Excessive parameters are ignored. If you want
>   to reject such requests, configure a FailedRequestFilter.

Comment: Might be helpful to include the new parameter/attribute value from server.xml.

Comment: Thanks. Better late than never :-)

Comment: I have a related error  in Tomcat 6: `Parameter count exceeded allowed maximum: 512` When adding  `maxParameterCount=10000` to server.xml it does nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: Your tomcat instance might be grabbing the default server.xml instead of yours? not sure tbh.